# Сделать вкладки внутри страницы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Хочу сделать вкладки на странице,
Например как в Google Chrome.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var tab; // заголовок вкладки
var tabContent; // блок содержащий контент вкладки


window.onload = function() {
  tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabContent');
  tab = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
  hideTabsContent(1);
}

document.getElementById('tabs').onclick = function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.className == 'tab') {
    for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
      if (target == tab[i]) {
        showTabsContent(i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function hideTabsContent(a) {
  for (var i = a; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
    tabContent[i].classList.remove('show');
    tabContent[i].classList.add("hide");
    tab[i].classList.remove('whiteborder');
  }
}

function showTabsContent(b) {
  if (tabContent[b].classList.contains('hide')) {
    hideTabsContent(0);
    tab[b].classList.add('whiteborder');
    tabContent[b].classList.remove('hide');
    tabContent[b].classList.add('show');
  }
}
```

```css
#tabs .tab {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

#tabs .whiteborder {
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#tabs .tabContent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px
}

#tabs .hide {
  display: none;
}

#tabs .show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <div class="tab whiteborder">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="tabContent">1</div>
  <div class="tabContent">2</div>
  <div class="tabContent">3</div>
</div>
```