# Сверстать div в форме трапеции с закруглёнными углами

Tags: html, css

Как сделать DIV по форме как вкладки в Chrome - трапеция с закругленными углами?

Comment: есть какой то пример картинка ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сделать вкладки внутри страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869598/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b)

Comment: @norbornen Это не дубль. Там о механизме создания вкладок, а тут именно о стиле. Хотя, конечно, можно было объединить в одном вопросе, но всё же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать перспективу и повороты:

```css
#tab {
  perspective: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.con_wrap, .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

.con_wrap {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 3rem;
  transform: rotateX(30deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">
  <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
   </div>
   <div class="con_wrap">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В Firefox текст жутко мыльный

Comment: Можно по-другому тогда сделать
Подправил, теперь не мылиться